# What is the best way to optimize the performance of those Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, average

I have this function that generate data for a HighChart chart. But it is very very very slow. It take 2.3 seconds to generate only 1 device for 24 hours even if there is no data at all in the Database. I normally have between 10 and 100 device to chart! Is there anyway to optimize those querySet ?

```
def getVacChart(self, fromDate, toDate):
        if((toDate - fromDate).days <= 1):
            avgMinutes = 15
        elif((toDate - fromDate).days <= 2):
            avgMinutes = 30
        elif((toDate - fromDate).days <= 3):
            avgMinutes = 45
        else:
            avgMinutes = 60
        totalReadings = int(((toDate - fromDate).total_seconds() / 60) / avgMinutes)
        readings = self.vacReading.filter(timeStamp__gte = fromDate).filter(timeStamp__lte = toDate).order_by('timeStamp')
        i = 0
        _from = fromDate + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (i * avgMinutes))
        _middle = int(round((_from + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (avgMinutes / 2)) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())) * 1000
        _to = _from + datetime.timedelta(minutes = avgMinutes)
        
        data = []
        if(toDate > datetime.datetime.now()):
            stop = datetime.datetime.now()
        else:
            stop = toDate
        lastAvgRdg = None
        while _from <= stop:
            avgRdg =  readings.filter(timeStamp__gte = _from).filter(timeStamp__lte = _to).aggregate(Avg('vacuum'))["vacuum__avg"]
            if(avgRdg is not None):
                avgRdg = round(avgRdg, 1)
                lastAvgRdg = avgRdg
            else:
                if(lastAvgRdg is not None):
                    avgRdg = lastAvgRdg
            data.append([_middle, avgRdg])
            i += 1
            _from = fromDate + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (i * avgMinutes))
            _middle = int(round((_from + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (avgMinutes / 2)) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())) * 1000
            _to = _from + datetime.timedelta(minutes = avgMinutes)
        return data
```

Comment: index timestamp, also use if avgRdg.exists() instead if(avgRdg is not None) this will avoid loading queryset into memory.

Answer (score 0):

IF it can help someone else, i have found this to be working very fast going from 15 seconds to less then a second! If someone see an even better way to do it or a way to optimize it even more, it would be awesome!!

```
def getVacChart(self, fromDate, toDate):
    readings = self.vacReading.filter(timeStamp__gte = fromDate).filter(timeStamp__lte = toDate).annotate(
        hour=ExtractHour("timeStamp"),
        minute=ExtractMinute("timeStamp"),
    ).annotate(
        minute=Case(
            When(minute__gte=0, minute__lt=15, then=Value('7')),
            When(minute__gte=15, minute__lt=30, then=Value('22')),
            When(minute__gte=30, minute__lt=45, then=Value('37')),
            When(minute__gte=45, then=Value('52')),
            output_field=CharField(),
        )
    ).annotate(average = Avg('vacuum'))
    data = []
    for rdg in readings:
        rdg.second = 30
        timeStamp = rdg.timeStamp.replace(minute=int(rdg.minute), second=30, microsecond=0) 
        epoch = (timeStamp - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds() * 1000
        data.append([epoch, rdg.average])
    return data
```